# Linker error when using cmake and doctest.h (it's working without cmake)

Tags: c++, cmake, linker-errors, doctest

I have 3 files in my directory "`project`": `doctest.h` - the testing library, `doctest_main.cpp` - a file needed for the library, and `tests.cpp` - the file with tests.

`project/doctest_main.cpp`:

```
#define DOCTEST_CONFIG_IMPLEMENT_WITH_MAIN
#include "doctest.h"
```

`project/tests.cpp`:

```
#include "doctest.h"

TEST_CASE("Some test_case") {
    CHECK(2 + 2 == 4);
}
```

When I compile everything by hand, it works:

```
project> g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror doctest_main.cpp tests.cpp -o a
project> ./a
```

I tried to add CMake this way:

`project/CmakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Werror)

add_executable(
    doctest_main.cpp tests.cpp)
```

Now I need to build CMake. Let's follow the official tutorial:

```
project> mkdir build
project/build> cd build
project/build> cmake ..  # Ok!
project/build> cmake --build .  # Linker error
```

The error is as follows:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/doctest_main.cpp.dir/tests.cpp.o: in function `_DOCTEST_ANON_FUNC_2()':
tests.cpp:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to `doctest::detail::ResultBuilder::ResultBuilder(doctest::assertType::Enum, char const*, int, char const*, char const*, char const*)'
```

And a lot of undefined references after that. What should I do?

Comment: Name your executable. https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html

Comment: There's also this: https://github.com/onqtam/doctest/blob/master/doc/markdown/build-systems.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created an executable with the target name `doctest_main.cpp` and only a single source file.

The `add_executable` should be changed to the following to create a target with the name `a` which by default results in the executable built being named `a` (or `a.exe` on windows):

```
# extra whitespaces/newlines not needed below, but a personal style preference.
add_executable(a

    doctest_main.cpp
    tests.cpp
)
```

Furthermore I recommend adding header files as sources too, since IDEs like Visual Studio wouldn't list them under the header files belonging to the `a` target.